# Multi-dimensional outer-product in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I was doing MNIST dataset and trying to get a outer product of my two vectors `w_i(ith class)` and `a_k(kth sample)`.

The `w_i`, for `i = 0...9`, has 784 coordinates.

The `a_k`, for `k = 1...n`, also has 784 coordinates.

I created two arrays `w_ij` and `a_ij` which contain all ten classes and k samples. The shape of `w_ij` is (10, 784) and `a_ij` is (n, 784).

I was trying to get a result something like:

```
[[w_0 dot a_1, w_0 dot a_2, ... , w_0 dot a_n], # (first row)
[w_1 dot a_1, w_1 dot a_2, ..., w_1 dot a_n], # (second row)
...,
[w_9 dot a_1, ..., w_9 dot a_n]] # (nth row)
```

So the shape of array should be like `(10, n)`. I tried to use `scipy.outer(w_ij, a_k)` or `scipy.multiply.outer(w_ij, a_k)`. However, it led me to a result whose shape is `(7840, 784*n)`. Could someone direct me to the right path?

Comment: note: I was challenged that if I can get the result without using any loop. So I'm trying to avoid using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want the following:

```
res = np.einsum('pi,qi->pq', w, a)
```

Which is shorthand for the following in index notation:

```
res[p,q] = w[p,i]*a[q,i]
```

In this notation, the convention is to sum over all indices which do not appear in the output

---

However, note that `ij,jk->ik` is just the standard matrix product, and `ij->ji` is just the matrix transpose. So we can simplify this as follows

```
np.einsum('pi,qi->pq', w, a)   # as before
np.einsum('pi,iq->pq', w, a.T) # transpose and swapping indices cancel out
np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', w, a.T) # index names don't matter
w @ a.T                        # wait a sec, this is just matrix multiplication (python 3.5+)
```

Comment: or `np.dot(w, a.T)`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint!